# Can I wrap <tr> in something that doesn't influence table layout? (JSF2.0)

Tags: html, jsf-2

I have a `<table>`, and in it some `<tr>`s. All is aligned as long as none `<tr>` is wrapped in `<div>` or `<span>`.

I have to wrap it because I'm using JSF and I have to render this row sometimes and sometimes not. Code is:

```
<table>
<!-- some other TRs -->
<h:panelGroup id="wrapping">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.render}">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Some label
      </th>
      <td>
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
</table>
```

I need the "wrapping" because when inner panelGroup is not rendered, I need some ID in HTML for ajax. I need also inner `<h:panelGroup>` because I have to use JSF `rendered` attribute somewhere, and I can't use it on `<tr>`.

The problem is this way this row is wrapped in `<span>`, and it is no more aligned with other rows. The same about `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try <thead>, <tbody>, <tfooter>

**EDITED**

Here is example:

```
<table>
<thead id="headForAjax"> <!-- note on this-->
<!-- some other TRs -->
<h:panelGroup id="wrapping">
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.render}">
    <tr>
      <th>
        Some label
      </th>
      <td>
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.value}" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
</thead>
</table>
```

thead used to group header's rows, tbody - you can use to group common rows, and so on

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please provide some JSF snippet with mentioned tags?

Comment: @amorfis - just appended example of thead with id to be used in ajax

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix JSF and HTML tags like that. You're breaking abstractions all over the place and I bet you'll never get valid HTML that way (which is the reason why your layout breaks).

Instead of a HTML table, use a `<h:panelGrid>` and put the `rendered` attribute on the individual components of that row.

As for the ID, what do you need it for? If it's for JSF-supported Ajax, I don't think you can re-render just one row of a table. If you're doing "manual" Ajax, you could use the `rowClasses` attribute of the `panelGrid` to give one particular rendered `<tr>` a distinct class.

Comment: ID is for JSF ajax. You can rerender single row, no problem here. I'll look at `<h:panelGrid>`, thanks!